# A question on Newtonian dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

Imagine a trolley moving at constant velocity thus, no external force and momentum are conserved. Then at x kg/s sand is falling on that trolley and the velocity of the trolley will decrease as momentum is conserved. So what external force is required to keep the trolley moving at constant velocity i.e. the same velocity before sand dropped on the trolley?

Comment: This reads like a homework problem.

Comment: Yes it's inspired from question came in my exam. But I am curious to learn... 

Comment: A partial answer is below, suggest you edit your question to 'Imagine a trolley that is moving at constant velocity horizontally and sand is falling vertically on that trolley at xkg/s.  What force is required to keep the trolley moving at constant velocity?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in $$\vec{F}= m\vec{a}$$
since we want $\dot v=0$, then because force is the rate of change of momentum
$$ \vec{F}= \dot p=\dot m\vec{v}=x\vec{v} $$
We have the required result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the impulse equation

$Force \times time = mv-mu$

where $v$ and $u$ are the final and initial velocity of the sand.

Hint:  in this question it's easy to think about the sand falling vertically, but it's the horizontal component of momentum that you should concentrate on.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple Newton's law. If $p$ is the momentum of the trolley at any time $t$, then a change in momentum $$dp = d(mv) = m \,dv + v \,dm.$$
Since you are saying $dv = 0$, this means
$$dp = v\, dm.$$ Force is the rate of change of momentum, so
$$\frac{dp}{dt} = \mathrm{Force} = v \, \frac{dm}{dt}.$$